# Trouble understanding this remark on the Isomorphism theorems in Dummit and Foote.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is my first time studying Group Theory. I'm following Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote.

I can't seem to understand what they want to convey here. I have attached the pic of the remark below. Following are what I didn't understand.

How are we defining $ \Phi$ on G itself?

What does $\Phi$ *factors through* $N$ intuitively mean?

Thanks.

https://i.ibb.co/5cS4XV2/processed-3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The definition is $\Phi(g):=\varphi(gN)$.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that $\Phi$ factors through $N$ means that you can write $\Phi$ as $\varphi\circ\pi$, for some homomorphism $\varphi\colon G/N\longrightarrow H$, where $\pi\colon G\longrightarrow G/N$ is the natural projection ($\pi(g)=gN$). It means that $\Phi$ is constant on each coset of $G/N$.